# Tracking full browser activity in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

There's a website that contains some real time information.  I want to have a VB.Net windows application that monitors the page, and when it detects certain events it triggers some actions based on the data in the page.

I've been searching like crazy for some mechanism to "hook" into the browser and hopefully inspect the messages transmitted for the application to know how to react.

I've seen the SHDocVw COM object, which comes very close.  But when I use the BeforeNavigate2 event, it only seems to fire for GETs, and once I'm on the page where the information is displayed/refreshed the event is not raised.

Short of reverse engineering the page, or having to write some kind of proxy...is there a good way to do this in VB.Net?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method you can try:

1. Create a GreaseMonkey script embedded on the page to hook up events.
2. When changes occur, collect the changes in an array or display them on the screen.
3. Create a VB.Net webpage service to listen for POST requests.
4. Post using AJAX from your GreaseMonkey script to the webpage service, which then writes to a log file/database on your server.

Otherwise the proxy would probably be the next best method, providing the server isn't HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, I don't control the webpage I want to monitor.  It just contains the information I want to monitor and act upon under certain conditions.

Comment: Right.  That's why I suggested GreaseMonkey.  It allows you to embed your own scripts into webpages you don't own or control.  That's a more direct interface than trying to collect data over a proxy or using some custom web page control.